# iOS UIView subclass draw see-through text to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I want to draw text onto my subclass on `UIView` so that the text is cut out of the shape and the background behind the view shows through, just like in the OSX Mavericks logo found here.

- background image view
- `IBOutlet UIView *ViewTest`
- `IBOutlet UIlabel *labelTest alpha:0 style` (Show background image)

http://s25.postimg.org/tkf1sa3x9/1122.png

<sub>I would say that I'm more of an intermediate/early advanced iOS developer so feel free to throw some crazy solutions at me. I'd expect I'd have to override `drawRect` in order to do this.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use layer mask. Render text onto an image, and set that image as the mask of a layer and assign that layer as the mask of your view.

```
// Create your mask layer
CALayer* maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,yourMaskWidth ,yourMaskHeight);
maskLayer.contents = (__bridge id)[myTextRenderedImage CGImage];

// Apply the mask to your uiview layer        
yourUIView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

`myTextRenderedImage` is the image you render plain text on.

Comment: There's no UILabel. You render text on an image. Then set it as content of the mask layer.

Comment: Can I uitextview.layer Instead of myTextRenderedImage CGImage ? I hope to help